# Freemarker How to pass a HashMap to a TemplateMethodModel

Tags: freemarker

I have a MyMethod class that implements TemplateMethodModel. I need to pass a HashMap to the args of the exec function.

How can I do that from a ftl template ?

FYI I have tried ${myMethod({"key":"value"})} but inside curly brackets are not accepted..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `TemplateMethodModelEx`, as `TemplateMethodModel` converts the arguments to string (it's a legacy...). (You still won't get a `HashMap`, but a `TemplateHashModelEx`.)